# tcpdump boost upload speed

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I have a server running Ubuntu where I installed Plex Media Server. The server has an Armhf processor and 2GB of RAM.

I am having issues with download speed. The server has 250Mbits link and the latency between my machine and the server is about 25ms (as shown by ping).

The download speed is capped around 635KB/s and when I tweaked the settings by adding

```
net.core.rmem_max=33554432
net.core.wmem_max=33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 33554432 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 33554432 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=1
net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 31
```

the download speed sometimes goes at around 835KB/s. A year ago when I didn't have a good connection, the speed was capped at 550KB/s. I can max the speed if I used multithreaded streams.

I ran tcpdump to investigate using the command:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 'tcp port 32400' -v -nn
```

The download speed is now around 5MB/s which is the bite rate of the video I'm streaming. When I stop tcpdump the speed drops at around 835KB/s

I see this behaviour only when streaming from the Android app but not when streaming through the LG TV app.

Here are the ouput of tcpdump when streaming through the TV app

```
   SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x3045), seq 52636:54084, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840404 ecr 1397725], length 1448
12:08:02.338704 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41187, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x4403), seq 54084:55532, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840404 ecr 1397725], length 1448
12:08:02.338727 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41188, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xa9cc), seq 55532:56980, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840404 ecr 1397725], length 1448
12:08:02.338734 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41189, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xc291), seq 56980:58428, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840404 ecr 1397725], length 1448
12:08:02.341785 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 32606, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x74ac (correct), ack 39604, win 870, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397727 ecr 3236840402], length 0
12:08:02.347411 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 31812, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59794 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x2003 (correct), ack 11030, win 661, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397727 ecr 3236840402], length 0
12:08:02.348702 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41190, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x2b1e), seq 58428:59876, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840405 ecr 1397727], length 1448
12:08:02.348723 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41191, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1426)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd2c9 (incorrect -> 0x4c36), seq 59876:61250, ack 1561, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840405 ecr 1397727], length 1374
12:08:02.355628 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 9026, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59797 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x43c4 (correct), ack 788, win 291, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397728 ecr 3236840399], length 0
12:08:02.382258 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 32607, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x20ec (correct), ack 61250, win 660, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397731 ecr 3236840402], length 0
12:08:02.432111 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 49296, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.60202 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x7eb3 (correct), ack 729, win 216, options [nop,nop,TS val 22239017 ecr 3236840397], length 0
12:08:02.432171 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53129, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 377)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.60202: Flags [P.], cksum 0xceb0 (incorrect -> 0xfa82), seq 729:1054, ack 88, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840413 ecr 22239017], length 325
12:08:02.441024 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 32608, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 83)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0xedcc (correct), seq 1561:1592, ack 61250, win 660, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397736 ecr 3236840402], length 31
12:08:02.441061 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41192, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [.], cksum 0xcd6b (incorrect -> 0x2330), ack 1592, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840414 ecr 1397736], length 0
12:08:02.441215 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41193, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59796: Flags [F.], cksum 0xcd6b (incorrect -> 0x232f), seq 61250, ack 1592, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840414 ecr 1397736], length 0
12:08:02.444571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 32609, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [R.], cksum 0x1fe3 (correct), seq 1592, ack 61250, win 885, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397736 ecr 3236840402], length 0
12:08:02.446246 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23728, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [S], cksum 0x5133 (correct), seq 620891993, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1397737 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
12:08:02.446338 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [S.], cksum 0xcd73 (incorrect -> 0xb4f8), seq 3963908859, ack 620891994, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3236840414 ecr 1397737,nop,wscale 10], length 0
12:08:02.454698 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 49297, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.60202 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x7d55 (correct), ack 1054, win 218, options [nop,nop,TS val 22239024 ecr 3236840413], length 0
12:08:02.466275 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 12891, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [R], cksum 0x49e3 (correct), seq 4258542270, win 0, length 0
12:08:02.466307 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 12892, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    HOME_IP.59796 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [R], cksum 0x49e3 (correct), seq 4258542270, win 0, length 0
12:08:02.469819 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23729, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x5401 (correct), ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397739 ecr 3236840414], length 0
12:08:02.469879 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23730, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 575)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5aa9 (correct), seq 1:524, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397739 ecr 3236840414], length 523
12:08:02.469932 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12573, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xcd6b (incorrect -> 0x52ba), ack 524, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840417 ecr 1397739], length 0
12:08:02.499025 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12574, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xc11c), seq 1:1449, ack 524, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840419 ecr 1397739], length 1448
12:08:02.499038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12575, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xffeb), seq 1449:2897, ack 524, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840419 ecr 1397739], length 1448
12:08:02.499078 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12576, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xf146), seq 2897:4345, ack 524, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840420 ecr 1397739], length 1448
12:08:02.499085 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12577, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 763)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd032 (incorrect -> 0x75d5), seq 4345:5056, ack 524, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840420 ecr 1397739], length 711
12:08:02.521870 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23731, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x4c17 (correct), ack 1449, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397744 ecr 3236840419], length 0
12:08:02.521917 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23732, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x4642 (correct), ack 2897, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397744 ecr 3236840419], length 0
12:08:02.521940 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23733, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x406c (correct), ack 4345, win 364, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397744 ecr 3236840420], length 0
12:08:02.521959 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23734, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x3d77 (correct), ack 5056, win 410, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397744 ecr 3236840420], length 0
12:08:02.531015 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23735, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 127)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0x62e2 (correct), seq 524:599, ack 5056, win 410, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397745 ecr 3236840420], length 75
12:08:02.531392 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23736, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 58)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2519 (correct), seq 599:605, ack 5056, win 410, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397745 ecr 3236840420], length 6
12:08:02.531752 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23737, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 97)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1852 (correct), seq 605:650, ack 5056, win 410, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397745 ecr 3236840420], length 45
12:08:02.533183 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12578, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xcd6b (incorrect -> 0x3e71), ack 650, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840423 ecr 1397745], length 0
12:08:02.533839 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12579, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 103)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [P.], cksum 0xcd9e (incorrect -> 0xc49f), seq 5056:5107, ack 650, win 30, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840423 ecr 1397745], length 51
12:08:02.558714 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 23738, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 968)
    HOME_IP.59798 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [P.], cksum 0x18ec (correct), seq 650:1566, ack 5107, win 410, options [nop,nop,TS val 1397748 ecr 3236840423], length 916
12:08:02.573968 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12580, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [P.], cksum 0xcee1 (incorrect -> 0x8fa8), seq 5107:5481, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840427 ecr 1397748], length 374
12:08:02.575235 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12581, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x4f0f), seq 5481:6929, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840427 ecr 1397748], length 1448
12:08:02.575245 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12582, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xa9f1), seq 6929:8377, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840427 ecr 1397748], length 1448
12:08:02.575290 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12583, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x90a1), seq 8377:9825, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840427 ecr 1397748], length 1448
12:08:02.575297 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12584, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xd772), seq 9825:11273, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840427 ecr 1397748], length 1448
12:08:02.582532 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12585, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.59798: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x3087), seq 11273:12721, ack 1566, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236840428 ecr 1397748], length 1448
12:08:02.582545 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12586, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
```

Here the logs when streaming through the android app

```
12:16:14.236701 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28996, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xd9c9), seq 23858662:23860110, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889460 ecr 22332949], length 1448
12:16:14.237959 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51063, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x5279 (correct), ack 23844182, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332952 ecr 3236889458], length 0
12:16:14.245223 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51064, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x472c (correct), ack 23847078, win 3063, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332954 ecr 3236889458], length 0
12:16:14.246725 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28997, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x3d90), seq 23860110:23861558, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889461 ecr 22332954], length 1448
12:16:14.246735 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28998, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xd5c0), seq 23861558:23863006, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889461 ecr 22332954], length 1448
12:16:14.246762 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28999, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xa94a), seq 23863006:23864454, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889461 ecr 22332954], length 1448
12:16:14.246769 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29000, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x9ad7), seq 23864454:23865902, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889461 ecr 22332954], length 1448
12:16:14.248756 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51065, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x3bd5 (correct), ack 23849974, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332955 ecr 3236889459], length 0
12:16:14.248815 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x2add (correct), ack 23854318, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332955 ecr 3236889459], length 0
12:16:14.256850 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29001, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x5da4), seq 23865902:23867350, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889462 ecr 22332955], length 1448
12:16:14.256862 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29002, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xcefe), seq 23867350:23868798, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889462 ecr 22332955], length 1448
12:16:14.256896 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29003, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xc49b), seq 23868798:23870246, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889462 ecr 22332955], length 1448
12:16:14.256903 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29004, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x216f), seq 23870246:23871694, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889462 ecr 22332955], length 1448
12:16:14.257888 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51067, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0x1439 (correct), ack 23860110, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332958 ecr 3236889460], length 0
12:16:14.266809 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29005, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x1377), seq 23871694:23873142, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889463 ecr 22332958], length 1448
12:16:14.266821 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29006, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x8e09), seq 23873142:23874590, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889463 ecr 22332958], length 1448
12:16:14.266855 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29007, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x1512), seq 23874590:23876038, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889463 ecr 22332958], length 1448
12:16:14.266861 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29008, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x53b5), seq 23876038:23877486, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889463 ecr 22332958], length 1448
12:16:14.268871 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51068, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0xfd9f (correct), ack 23865902, win 3057, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332961 ecr 3236889461], length 0
12:16:14.276848 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29009, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x2c18), seq 23877486:23878934, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889464 ecr 22332961], length 1448
12:16:14.276859 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29010, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x46f8), seq 23878934:23880382, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889464 ecr 22332961], length 1448
12:16:14.276891 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29011, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x8f1b), seq 23880382:23881830, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889464 ecr 22332961], length 1448
12:16:14.276897 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29012, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x1317), seq 23881830:23883278, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889464 ecr 22332961], length 1448
12:16:14.277998 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51069, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0xf240 (correct), ack 23868798, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332964 ecr 3236889462], length 0
12:16:14.278054 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51070, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0xe6f0 (correct), ack 23871694, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332964 ecr 3236889462], length 0
12:16:14.286870 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29013, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x9a46), seq 23883278:23884726, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889465 ecr 22332964], length 1448
12:16:14.286882 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29014, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x4070), seq 23884726:23886174, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889465 ecr 22332964], length 1448
12:16:14.286917 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29015, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xa15e), seq 23886174:23887622, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889465 ecr 22332964], length 1448
12:16:14.286924 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29016, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x7bb9), seq 23887622:23889070, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889465 ecr 22332964], length 1448
12:16:14.290811 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51071, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0xd04b (correct), ack 23877486, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332968 ecr 3236889463], length 0
12:16:14.296850 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29017, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xdfde), seq 23889070:23890518, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889466 ecr 22332968], length 1448
12:16:14.296861 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29018, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0x0a96), seq 23890518:23891966, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889466 ecr 22332968], length 1448
12:16:14.296889 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29019, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xce97), seq 23891966:23893414, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889466 ecr 22332968], length 1448
12:16:14.296896 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29020, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    SERVER_IP.32400 > HOME_IP.61313: Flags [.], cksum 0xd313 (incorrect -> 0xb825), seq 23893414:23894862, ack 1097, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 3236889466 ecr 22332968], length 1448
12:16:14.297114 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 51072, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    HOME_IP.61313 > SERVER_IP.32400: Flags [.], cksum 0xc4f8 (correct), ack 23880382, win 3068, options [nop,nop,TS val 22332970 ecr 3236889464], length 0
```

Here are the result of my testing with iperf3

```
ubuntu@root ~ [1]> iperf3 -c SERVER_IP -R
Connecting to host SERVER_IP, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host SERVER_IP is sending
[  5] local 10.0.2.15 port 43990 connected to SERVER_IP port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   602 KBytes  4.93 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   570 KBytes  4.67 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   565 KBytes  4.63 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   576 KBytes  4.72 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   565 KBytes  4.62 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   576 KBytes  4.72 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   565 KBytes  4.62 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   570 KBytes  4.67 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   570 KBytes  4.67 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   566 KBytes  4.64 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  27.5 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  5.59 MBytes  4.69 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Here are the result with multithreaded:

```
[SUM]   0.00-10.03  sec   160 MBytes   134 Mbits/sec  271             sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec   140 MBytes   118 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Do you know what is causing my issues? I know that I don't have I/O accounting support with my current kernel and perhaps other things.

Comment: Try again but this time launch `tcpdump` with `--no-promiscuous-mode`. Does it also lead to better performance?

Comment: @DanielB I have the same behavior even with at argument